# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I usesd groupby to get the table below

```
    time_groups=time_data.groupby('time_binned').mean()
    time_groups
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

Then I try to build a bar chart to show the 'Status' column result, 
but I got error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

```
plt.bar(time_groups.index.astype(str),100*time_groups['Status'])
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't pass strings as the first argument to `plt.bar`. Instead use something like `range(len(time_groups.index))` and adjust the labels later on via [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

Comment: `time_groups[['status']].plot.bar()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see the error is because the first argument (x) is required to be numeric. This is because you're specifying the x-coordinates of the plot. Try doing this:

```
plt.bar(x = np.arange(0, len(time_groups['Status'])), height = time_groups['Status'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(time_groups['Status'])), time_groups.index.values)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Vishnu, it shows another error bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'left'

Comment: Quick question Kunchur, what about if I want to use time_binned column data as my xsticks, do you know what will be the good method to do that?

Comment: It solved, I used the code you worte above and it works.  Thank you very much.